# Want to Access Tabs thru page code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have created a page where I have implemented many tabs by ajax control toolkit.
Now I want to access that tabs from implemented page's code behind.
How can I Do this.

Comment: Are you wanting to access them on a postback, or are you saying you want to access them on the initial page request?

Comment: I want to access them on button click.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
        <asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0">
           <asp:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel1" ID="TabPanel1">
              <HeaderTemplate />
              <ContentTemplate>
                  //CONTROLS COMES HERE
              </ContentTemplate>
           </asp:TabPanel>  
        </asp:TabContainer>
```

Comment: It is not looking like answer.